# BPXWUNIX: not found error when trying to run Regina Rexx script

Tags: java, shell, sh, oorexx, netrexx

I have made a logfile reader in Java that is supposed to alert me via Xymon when more than 1 redis servers is down simultaneously.

Now I am supposed to feed the output to Xymon via a Rexx script and I tried to do that by calling the command to run the Java program using bpxwunix.

However, when I run the code to test it, it says: "sh: 1: BPXWUNIX not found".

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, I've been searching for a method to somehow include the bpxwunix function but it is my understanding that this is not necesarry.

I'm pretty sure the Rexx script is the problem because I tried a blank Java program that just prints a single line and got the same error. Also tried to just run the program in the command line with java -jar and it runs fine.

I am talking about Regina Rexx (even though it says oorexx and netrexx in the tags, I couldn't add a new rexx tag because my reputation was not high enough). 
And I am trying this on Ubuntu 18.04.

Anyone that can help me out? Please alert me if I missed any details! The rexx code is provided below:

```
/* rexx */

env.0=1
env.1="/usr/bin:.:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin:."

stdin.0=0

reader="/home/slave2/Downloads/LogFileReader.jar"

cmd="java -jar reader"

call bpxwunix cmd,stdin.,stdout.,stderr.,env.

SAY "stdout:"

exit
```

Comment: It is looking for the **rexx procedure** `BPXWUNIX` and can not find it

Comment: This document https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxb600/wunix.htm suggests bpxwunix is zOS unix command. Are you running on ZOS

Comment: Why the netrexx tag? And everything points to this running on a PC type machine not a mainframe and BPXWUNIX is a mainframe utility. Sorry this is a bit late but OP has not come back to give further details - maybe this will jog their thought process.

Answer (score 1):

IBM provides [BPXWUNIX](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxb600/wunix.htm) as a built-in command in the z/OS operating system. If you're not running there — and your mention of Regina Rexx implies that you're not — then the command won't be available.